# add javascript variable to click to call link

Tags: javascript, html, variables, mobile, href

What I am trying to do is add a javascript variable to a click to call href so that whenever the phone number changes from the javascript the click to call href will change as well. The javascript that defines the variable has a default value (ex: 1-800-555-1212), but can change whenever the page loads where the tfid defines a different phone number (ex: http://www.domain.com?tfid=8663337777)

Here's an example of what's there currently:

```
<a href="tel:<this phone number needs to be dynamic as well>">Call this number: <script language="javascript" >
  key = getVar("keyword");
  tn = getVar("tfid");
  source = getVar("source");
  content = getVar("content");
  campaign = getVar("campaign");
  if(tn!="")
  {
  setcookie(key,tn);
  }
  getcookie(); 
  </script></a>
```

EDIT:

In order to show all elements to how the phone number is shown or switched out, I've included the javascript below that is called whenever a page loads:

```
// JavaScript Document start
//function to set cookie from the URL
function pixelfire(debug)
{
var phone_number=getVar("phone_number");
var keyword=getVar("keyword");
var source=getVar("source");
if(keyword)
{
    //document.write("set phone number "+phone_number);
    //document.write("set keyword "+keyword);
    setcookie(keyword,phone_number);
    //document.write("back from set cookie");
}
else
{
    var keyword=get_named_cookie("MM_Keyword");
    var phone_number=get_named_cookie("MM_TrackableNumber");
    //document.write("retrieved keyword "+keyword);
    //document.write("retrieved phone number "+phone_number);
    if(keyword)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
if(debug)
{
document.write("here are cookies<BR><P>"+document.cookie);
}
var campaign=getVar("campaign");
var content=getVar("content");
//document.write("location is "+location);
var url="http://www.mongoosemetrics.com/pixelfire.php?phone_number="+phone_number;
var url = url + "&keyword="+keyword;
var url = url + "&source="+source;
var url = url + "&campaign="+campaign;
var url = url + "&content="+content;

//document.write("url is "+ url);
myImage= new Image();
myImage.src=url;
}

function setcookie(key,tn,path){
        index = -1;
        var today = new Date();
        today.setTime( today.getTime() );
        var cookie_expire_date = new Date(today.getTime() + (365* 86400000)); 
        document.cookie="MM_TrackableNumber="+tn+";path=/;expires="+cookie_expire_date.toGMTString();
        document.cookie="MM_Keyword="+key+";path=/;expires="+cookie_expire_date.toGMTString();
}
//function to retrive the cookie
function getcookie(){
    //plcae your default phone number to show in case cookie is not set
    defaultphone="8005551212";
    if(document.cookie){ //check if there is a cookie set 
          index = document.cookie.indexOf("MM_TrackableNumber");

          if (index != -1){
                namestart = (document.cookie.indexOf("=", index) + 1);
                nameend = document.cookie.indexOf(";", index);
                if (nameend == -1) {nameend = document.cookie.length;}
                document.write(formatnumber(document.cookie.substring(namestart, nameend)));

          }

            else
            {
            document.write(formatnumber(defaultphone));
            }
    }
    else
    {
    document.write(formatnumber(defaultphone));
    }
}
function get_named_cookie(name)
{
    if(document.cookie)
    {
        index=document.cookie.indexOf(name);
        if (index != -1)
        {
            namestart = (document.cookie.indexOf("=", index) + 1);
                        nameend = document.cookie.indexOf(";", index);
                        if (nameend == -1) {nameend = document.cookie.length;}
            var ret_one = document.cookie.substring(namestart, nameend);
            return ret_one; 
        }
    }
}
//function to format the phonenumber to (123) 456-7890
function formatnumber(num)
{
    _return="1-";
    var ini = num.substring(0,3);
    _return+=ini+"-";
    var st = num.substring(3,6);
    _return+=st+"-";
    var end = num.substring(6,10);
    _return+=end;
    return _return;
}
function getVar(name)
         {
         get_string = document.location.search;         
         return_value = '';

         do { //This loop is made to catch all instances of any get variable.
            name_index = get_string.indexOf(name + '=');

            if(name_index != -1)
              {
              get_string = get_string.substr(name_index + name.length + 1, get_string.length - name_index);

              end_of_value = get_string.indexOf('&');
              if(end_of_value != -1)                
                value = get_string.substr(0, end_of_value);                
              else                
                value = get_string;                

              if(return_value == '' || value == '')
                 return_value += value;
              else
                 return_value += ', ' + value;
              }
            } while(name_index != -1)

         //Restores all the blank spaces.
         space = return_value.indexOf('+');
         while(space != -1)
              { 
              return_value = return_value.substr(0, space) + ' ' + 
              return_value.substr(space + 1, return_value.length);

              space = return_value.indexOf('+');
              }

         return(return_value);        
         }

/*end*/
```

As simple as this may sound (which *I know* it's not), I need the `<a>` tag to do this: `<a href="tel:FILL THIS WITH EITHER THE DEFAULT NUMBER OR THE NEW NUMBER DEFINED BY THE TFID URL">`

Comment: Since the phone number appears to be known at page load, I would just set the correct value when loading the page instead of trying to solve things in javascript.

Comment: How would that be accomplished so that the href would show either the default number or the new number within the code so that it allows the click to call to work? href="tel:1-800-NEW-PHONE"

Comment: I'm just assuming that you're using some serverside language in which you can change the html that will be sent to the browser.

Comment: The javascript above makes a call to a script that allows either the default number to be shown, a new number to be shown as defined by the TFID URL string, as well as set a cookie so that the phone number shows throughout the website.

Comment: I guess I'm not seeing the same things. I can't see a call to a script that shows a default number or any other number.

Comment: I've added the script that is called so you can see all elements involved in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store the phonenumber into the ID of the  then use this script

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".clickable").onClick(function() {   
          var phone = $(this).attr('id')
       }); 
  }); 

</script>

<a class="clickable" id="{variable_phone_number}" href="...."> ... </a>
```

EDIT: Try this

```
<a class="clickable" id="+298384858849" href="...."> ... </a>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var number = $(".clickable").attr('id')

    });

</script>
```

Remember to add the id and the class attributes

Comment: Would this allow the variable phone number to be passed to the href so that the click to call would work? href="tel:1-800-NEW-PHONE"

Comment: the href remain the same

Comment: i tried to add `code`var = document.getElementById('tfid');`code` to the original javascript and added `code`id="tfid"`code` to the <a> tag but then the javascript didn't run

Comment: I'd like to add that your javascript code DID allow the mobile "Click to Call" to open, but since a phone number isn't passed to the <a> tag then the phone call launches without a phone number that's dialed. I think we're on the right track here, and if we can just get that phone number to pass then I think it will solve the problem.

Comment: You have to find the way to pass the number to the id attribute.. however you need to check jquery mobile and find something.. bye

Comment: i've added `code`var tfid = document.getElementById('tfid');`code` and changed the <a> tag to `code`<a class="clickable" id="tfid" href="tel:">`code` (couldn't leave it blank or add the .... like you had otherwise it fills it in with the URL path of the webpage it's on)......it must have the tel: within the href and hopefully add the dynamic element immediately after it.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe want to wrap it in a function?

```
<a onclick="doSomething('123456789')" href="tel:<this phone number needs to be dynamic as well>">Call this number: </a>

<script language="javascript" >
function doSomething(telNumber){
  var tel = telNumber;
  key = getVar("keyword");
  tn = getVar("tfid");
  source = getVar("source");
  content = getVar("content");
  campaign = getVar("campaign");
  if(tn!="")
  {
    setcookie(key,tn);
  }
  getcookie(); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: when I tried to wrap the javascript into the function it prevented the phone number from displaying......ie, Call this number: 1-800-555-1212, and instead just showed Call this number: